# Drupal_add_css drupal_add_js not working dynamically

Tags: 7, javascript

I am working on a drupal-7 project that have many CSS/JS files that need to be added dynamically.
This is the code which i am using in `mymodule_init()`

```
function doLookup($baseRootDir)
    {
    if (variable_get('xmldata')) {
        $xmldata = variable_get('xmldata');
    } else {
        $xmldata = '';
    }
    $rootDir = realpath($baseRootDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $xmldata);
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootDir);
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
        $fileInfo = new SplFileInfo($filename);
        if (strtolower($fileInfo->getExtension()) == "css") {
            // Include this CSS file in drupal
            drupal_add_css($cssFileName, array('type' => "file", 'group' => CSS_DEFAULT, 'every_page' => TRUE));
        } elseif (strtolower($fileInfo->getExtension()) == "js") {
            // Include this JS file in drupal
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function in `hook_init()` which doesn't seem to be working. I have tried clearing drupal cache as well. 
Please help me out i need to complete this asap :(

Comment: Make sure that function is actually being called, drop a drupal_set_message in it. After that your directory file scan looks suspect and unnecessarily slow.

Comment: Yes i have tried that. Function is being called and control is going in inner most `if` condition as well. Also what is suspicious in this dir scan please let me know if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Personally I would hardcode the location of the CSS/JS files. If that's not possible try using https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_scan_directory/7

Comment: That i have just implemented but still CSS are not loading up in `hook_init()`.